# preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '?'

Tags: php, regex

The follwing code gives me an error "preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '?'"

```
$str = 'background: url("../../dsdgsd/contain.jpg");';

echo preg_replace('/url\s?\(\s?(\"|\')([../?]*[a-z/]*?[/?]?)([a-z0-9_-]*[.][jpg|jpeg|png|jpeg]*)([\'|\"]\))/gi','url("../images/$3")',$str);
```

Comment: How familiar are you with the [regex syntax](http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)? Either use a delimiter that's less likely to occur in the pattern itself, e.g. `#`, or escape every instance of `/` in the pattern.

Comment: Whoever wrote this regexp, mixed up `[` and `(` (apart from various other issues). E.g. this: `[../?]*` should probably read `(\\.\\./)*`, i.e. "a repeated occurrence of `../`"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what this regexp is supposed to be doing, but the error is given because you have `/` characters in the pattern. The parser then thinks your pattern is done, and takes everything after it (which is `?` in this case) as modifier. Hence the error.

Fix by using another separator: (most people use `#` when dealing with a lot of `/`)

```
echo preg_replace('#url\s?\(\s?(\"|\')([../?]*[a-z/]*?[/?]?)([a-z0-9_-]*[.][jpg|jpeg|png|jpeg]*)([\'|\"]\))#i','url("../images/$3")',$str);
```

(apart from this, as has been mentioned, the `g` modifier is not needed)

Comment: thanks buddy, it worked perfectly... The concept of "#" is awesome...

Answer (score 1):

For `preg_replace`, it is not necessary to use the `global` modifier `g` (should not use), it already replace globally.

[There is no g modifier in php.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Answer (score 1):

Since you start the regex with a `/` character, it is a delimiter, and you should escape all occurrences of `/` inside the regex. Because the first character after the second `/` is `?`, it is interpreted as a modifier.